# Getting error _reactApollo.connect(0, mapQueriesToProps) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using react-apollo client and ApolloProvider to connect my component with queryprops function to render data but I am getting this error undefined is not a function(evaluating(_reactApollo.connect)(mapQueriesToProps))

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect, gql, graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

class ProductsScreen extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('component is going to render');
    }

    renderProducts() {
        if (this.props.data.loading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <Text>{ this.props.data.shop.name }</Text>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
              { this.renderProducts() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapQueriesToProps = ({ ownProps, state }) => {
  return {
            query: gql`query {
                  shop {
                      name
                      primaryDomain {
                        url
                        host
                      }
                    }
             }`
        };
};

export default connect(mapQueriesToProps)(ProductsScreen);
```

Comment: I believe react-apollo doesn't have any connect function. connect usually belongs to react-redux library.

Comment: They do provide connect function. I followed the example provided in their documentation.

Comment: can you show me the link for the example please

Comment: https://github.com/saikat/docs/blob/master/source/apollo-client/react.md

Comment: official docs example here ... http://dev.apollodata.com/react/initialization.html

Comment: can you change `this.renderProducts()` to `this.renderProducts.bind(this)` and give it a try

Comment: export default graphql(
  gql`query {
        shop {
            name
            primaryDomain {
              url
              host
            }
          }
   }`)(ProductsScreen);
   
that's how I resolved the issue by passing graphql(myquery)(mycomponent) instead of connect function.

Comment: please add it as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

You should import `gql from 'graphql-tag'`
Check the migration docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/2.0-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why connect function of react apollo does not work.
So I resolved the issue by calling graphql function instead of connect function and passed myQuery as an argument. like this:

export default graphql(myQuery)(MyComponent);